# Make an element appear and make adjustments when hovering over another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mediaelement.js

I'm having problems with my code. I have it set up properly to show a hidden div `mejs__horizontal-volume-slider` when you hover over `mejs__volume-button` and shift other elements to the right to accommodate `mejs__horizontal-volume-slider`. The problem I have is that `mejs__horizontal-volume-slider` disappears when you move off `mejs__volume-button`.

I'm looking for a way to show `mejs__horizontal-volume-slider` and adjust the volume when you hover over `mejs__volume-button` and move over to `mejs__horizontal-volume-slider`.

URL: http://wpfreelance.bayoumedia.net/audio/

JS code:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
$('.mejs__volume-button').hover(
function () {
 $('.mejs__horizontal-volume-slider').css({"display":"block"});
 $('.mejs__time-slider').css({"width":"-moz-calc(100% - 50px)"});
 $('.mejs__time-slider').css({"width":"-webkit-calc(100% - 50px)"});
 $('.mejs__time-slider').css({"width":"calc(100% - 50px)"});
 $('.mejs__speed-button').css({"right":"40px"});
},
function () {
 $('.mejs__horizontal-volume-slider').css({"display":"none"});
 $('.mejs__time-slider').css({"width":"100%"});
 $('.mejs__speed-button').css({"right":"0"});
});});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert the slider and the button in the same container, and trigger the hover effect with the container, so when you're moving over the slider, you're still hovering the container. It's probably better to use CSS by the way.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem with `wrapall`. I took `.mejs__volume-button` and `.mejs__horizontal-volume-slider` and wrapped them into a new div called `mejs__button mejs__group-volume`. The player requires `mejs__button` to calculate the width of the progress bar. With that added, I was able to wrap the volume elements into a new group.

`$( ".mejs__volume-button,.mejs__horizontal-volume-slider" ).wrapAll( "<div class='mejs__button mejs__group-volume' />")`